# TensorFlow keras callback using tensorboard. ProfilerNotRunningError: Cannot stop profiling. No profiler is running

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, callback

I am running into this  error: `Cannot stop profiling. No profiler is running`. Can it be related to `log_dir` ?

Before this issue, I had a problem with creating a directory. I have fixed it by manual creating dir. Can the error "Cannot stop profiling. No profiler is running" be related?

Please help

here is the code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten,Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

import pickle
import time

NAME = "car_and_sign"#.format(int(time.time()))

tensorboard=TensorBoard(log_dir='logs/{}'.format(NAME))

X=pickle.load(open("X.pickle","rb"))
y=pickle.load(open("y.pickle","rb"))

X=X/255

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="logs/{}".format(NAME))

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
             optimizer="adam",
             metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X,y,
          batch_size=32,
          epochs=3,
          validation_split=0.3,
          callbacks=[tensorboard])
```

The ERROR:

```
Train on 2935 samples, validate on 1258 samples
Epoch 1/3
WARNING:tensorflow:Trace already enabled
32/2935 [..............................] - ETA: 35s - loss: 0.7010 - 
accuracy: 0.5312Traceback (most recent call last):

File "F:\Python\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 753, in on_start
yield

File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 342, in fit
total_epochs=epochs)

File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 181, in run_one_epoch
step += 1

File "F:\Python\lib\contextlib.py", line 119, in __exit__
next(self.gen)

File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 788, in on_batch
mode, 'end', step, batch_logs)

File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 239, in _call_batch_hook
batch_hook(batch, logs)

File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 1695, in on_train_batch_end
self._log_trace()

File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 1747, in _log_trace
profiler_outdir=os.path.join(self._log_write_dir, 'train'))

File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\summary_ops_v2.py", line 1240, in trace_export
_profiler.save(profiler_outdir, _profiler.stop())

File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\profiler.py", line 99, in stop
'Cannot stop profiling. No profiler is running.')

ProfilerNotRunningError: Cannot stop profiling. No profiler is running.
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\malic\Documents\projects\Spide\train_loaddata.py", line 47, in <module>
callbacks=[tensorboard])

File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 819, in fit
use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)

File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 397, in fit
prefix='val_')

File "F:\Python\lib\contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)

File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 757, in on_start
self.callbacks._call_end_hook(mode)

File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 262, in _call_end_hook
self.on_train_end()

File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 379, in on_train_end
callback.on_train_end(logs)

File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 1720, in on_train_end
self._log_trace()

File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 1747, in _log_trace
profiler_outdir=os.path.join(self._log_write_dir, 'train'))

File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\summary_ops_v2.py", line 1240, in trace_export
_profiler.save(profiler_outdir, _profiler.stop())

File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\profiler.py", line 99, in stop
'Cannot stop profiling. No profiler is running.')

ProfilerNotRunningError: Cannot stop profiling. No profiler is running.
```

Answer (score 3):

In case someone stumbles upon this in the future:

The problem is the / in the logdir path as discussed in [this github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/2279). Just change the path to \\ and it should work.

So replace

`tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="logs/{}".format(NAME))`

with

`tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="logs\\{}".format(NAME))`

The reason is that in this tf version your path cannot contain forward slashes if it contains backward slashes. But since tensorflow appends more stuff to the logdir path (with a ) it fails.

Atleast thats what fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

For newer version of Tensorflow, you may try running the following :

`tf.profiler.experimental.stop()`